# Can't run PowerMock with JUnitParams

Tags: java, junit, junit4, powermock, junit-rule

I'm trying use PowerMock with JUnitParams, however I'm getting this strange error:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2852e4bb : com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2852e4bb
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2852e4bb
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2852e4bb
class               : com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDFTest
required-type       : com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDFTest
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1/outer-class/fNext/test/outer-class/fTest/sut
line number         : 8
class[1]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner
class[2]            : org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2
class[3]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement
class[4]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement
class[5]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1
version             : null
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
at org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:54)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:89)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2852e4bb
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.determineType(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:458)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:294)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
... 65 more
```

My test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({RequestContext.class, FacesContext.class})
public class ControladorExibicaoPDFTest {
    @Rule
    private PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    private ControladorExibicaoPDF sut = spy(new ControladorExibicaoPDF());
    private RequestContext contextoRequest = mock(RequestContext.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(RequestContext.class);
        mockStatic(FacesContext.class);
        when(RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(contextoRequest);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "parametrosTesteExibirPDF")
    public void testeExibirPDF(String caminhoArquivoPDF, String comandoEsperado) {
        sut.exibir(caminhoArquivoPDF);
        verify(contextoRequest).execute(comandoEsperado);
    }

    private Object[] parametrosTesteExibirPDF() {
        return $(
                $("/home/hudson/teste.pdf", "exibirRelatorio('/home/hudson/teste.pdf');"),
                $("/home/user/outro/adobe.pdf", " exibirRelatorio('/home/user/outro/adobe.pdf');"),
                $("c:\\documentos\\arquivo.pdf", " exibirRelatorio('c:\\documentos\\arquivo.pdf');"),
                $("c:\\outro.pdf", " exibirRelatorio('c:\\outro.pdf');"),
                $("/home/user/novo/arquivos/relatorios/relatorio.pdf", " exibirRelatorio('/home/user/novo/arquivos/relatorios/relatorio.pdf');")
        );
    }
}
```

and these are the maven dependencies:

[image: dependencies]

According with [this](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) post, I can use PowerMock with another JUnit's runner. However, I have no idea of why this is happening. What I did wrong here?

Comment: I have had issues using the `@Rule` based PowerMock approach combined with both JUnitParams and Mockito mock. The rule based approach combined with just JUnitParams seems to work. Try removing  the  `private RequestContext contextoRequest = mock(RequestContext.class);` Do you have both powermock rule agent and xstream jars?

Comment: @clD I've added the dependencies you mentioned, but I'm getting another error.

Comment: Are all the version numbers correct e.g. if using powermock 1.5.5 all the dependencies i.e. rule-agent, xstream etc will need to be set to <version>1.5.5</version> Also once that is setup I think there will be still be a problem with `RequestContext contextoRequest` as it is both `mock` and `mockStatic`.

Comment: @clD I changed the entire question. I think it is more clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of the dependencies in pom.xml to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The top three are needed first for @Rule and there seems to be a issue with how mocks are loaded by the different classloaders https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=362

Also the field annotated with `@Rule` must be `public`. `@Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();`

Then the test runs fine.

Comment: @cID I didn't have the powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent dependency. Changed the dependencies order too and it is running :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very related issue, from powermock's bug data base: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=350

From the stack trace that you have supplied, powermock is trying to deep copy a class (via xml) a class that cannot be serialized/deserialized like that.  There is a CGLib proxy amongst the transient relation ships of the class.

The proxy that it is having a problem with is called ' com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2852e4bb', so have a look at your code and see where com.lutum.web.ui.controladores.ControladorExibicaoPDF$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB is being used.  You need to ideally make it transient/recreatable after being serialized/deserialized.